# Login loop 14.04 but guest account is accessible

Tags: login, login-screen

After upgrading to 14.04 from 13.10 which worked fine, I cannot get past login as it just loops back. Guest account works fine. I can login to the console by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> using `username` and `password`. Not sure what is causing problem.

#### Update:

- Video card is **N9500GT**
- Tried `chown username:username .Xauthority` but now get only splash screen at login with password. Same thing happens in GDM.
- Also tried `sudo mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak` no change.
- Tried `cat ~/.xsession-errors` but got message that starts with can't save user-dirs.dirs and then gives more msgs and stops.

How to see what is in `.xsession-errors` file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I logged into my account via tty (by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it said that there was an error in the `~/.profile` file (I had been messing around in there).  After fixing the error I was able to log in.

Look for any error messages and try to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, but ended up fixing it.

It is not necessary to delete your `~/.profile`, but that file is what's causing the issue. Just make sure it doesn't print **anything** to STDOUT (and possibly STDERR as well).

Once I removed the printing from my `~/.profile` file, I was able to log in with GDM.

Answer (score 1):

As I encountered the login loop two days ago, I thought I should share. Anyway, this is for people new to Linux.

Searching for a solution in other threads, you will find there is one dominant solution: access privileges for both of the files, `.Xauthority` and `.IDEauthority`.

How to find whether or not you "own" those files?

Login as Guest, which you have probably done anyway to use the internet.

Open a login terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, or alternatively, + <kbd>F3</kbd>, + <kbd>F4</kbd>, and so on until <kbd>F6</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> brings you back to your Desktop, so you can switch back and forth.

(I will use Ubuntu version 14.04 on an ASUS-S400CA as an example.) You will see something like:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 ASUS-S400CA tty2
ASUS-S400CA login:
```

Type in your username. (Your username is the nickname you chose at installation, not your full name you may see on your actual login screen.), then type in your password.

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 ASUS-S400CA tty2
ASUS-S400CA login: yourusername
Password:
```

You should now see:

```
yourusername@ASUS-S400CA:~$
```

If your login loop is caused by missing access privileges for the files mentioned earlier, we can check it like this:

```
ls  -ld  ~/.*authority
```

If you then get

```
-rw------- 1 root root 2015 May  24 12:38 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 root root 2015 May  24 12:38 .Xauthority
```

instead of

```
-rw------- 1 yourusername yourusername 2015 May  24 12:38 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 yourusername yourusername 2015 May  24 12:38 .Xauthority
```

you have to use the `chown` command to get back your access privileges:

```
sudo  chown  yourusername:yourusername  ~/.Xauthority
```

and if necessary the same for `.IDEauthority`. Note that you will have to verify the result again with the ls command. No error message is a good sign, though.

Your shell does not recognize any of the commands you type in?

This could be the main cause for the login loop as `login` itself is just a command.

How to use commands under these circumstances?

The shell gives you two pieces of information: First, the command is not accessible. Second, it is found in, e.g.

```
/usr/bin
```

In this case the above mentioned code looks - depending on where "the executable" of the command is located in your system - something like this:

```
/usr/bin/ls -ld ~/.*authority
/usr/bin/sudo  /bin/chown   yourusername:yourusername   ~/.Xauthority
/usr/bin/sudo  /bin/chown   yourusername:yourusername   ~/.IDEauthority
```

The reason why your command prompt (shell, Terminal, command line) recognizes and executes commands - including the login command - is, because the paths to their directories - like /usr/bin, /bin, /sbin and so on - are all saved in a file. There they are given as the value to a variable called PATH. (For easy to understand explanations on Linux terms check out linfo.org. In this case [linfo.org/path_env_var.html](http://linfo.org/path_env_var.html))

To check, which paths are saved in PATH, type

```
echo $PATH
```

or its equivalent command with directory structure.

It will probably give you something like

```
/usr/local
```

However, it should look like:

```
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

The different directories between the colons can be arranged in any order.

To save those temporarily, and be able to use commands, type

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

To make those changes permanent, you have to save it in the respective file, where your PATH variable is defined.

Depending on your type of login shell, this could be a different file, as different login shells read certain files first. To find out what shell you are using, type `echo $SHELL` in your command line. Chances are you will get back `/bin/bash` anyway. (Also, the hints given to you by the Terminal on where to find the commands probably started with `-bash`.)  (For more information check out [What's the best distro/shell agnostic way to set environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856/%22See%20a%20post%20on%20login%20shell%22) and [Difference between login shell and non-login shell/46856#46856](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables))

If your shell is bash, the easiest option is to edit your `.profile` file in your home directory `~`, which is equivalent to `/home/yourusername`. If you temporarily saved your directories to your commands you can open that file by typing

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

This opens the file with the respective text editor gedit. (Just in case you do not have gedit for some reason, use the `aptitude` or `apt-get` command in combination with sudo and install gedit or any text editor you prefer: `sudo apt-get install gedit` .)

At the end of that file you probably find something like:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

PATH=usr/local
```

However, PATH should be defined just as described above. Simply, add the other directories:

```
PATH=/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

save the file, reboot your system, and you should (hopefully) be good to go.

[login](/questions/tagged/login) [loop](/questions/tagged/loop) [14.04](/questions/tagged/14.04) [cannot](/questions/tagged/cannot) [login-screen](/questions/tagged/login-screen)

Comment: `$SHELL` only gives the user's default shell, not the one they are running

Answer (score 0):

I had the same login loop problem and I tried everything I found online, but the only thing that worked was deleting large files I had. I guess I'd just run out of free space.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. and run the following command.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER
```

I am guessing the permissions to your /home folder has been altered somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.  This is what worked for me:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

provide login credentials, then run

```
sudo service lightdm stop     
sudo service lightdm start    
sudo startx
```

Answer (score -1):

Boot using terminal then type:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

remove anything if you wrote there earlier.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>to exit.

You can read more [in this it'sFOSS post](http://itsfoss.com/disable-guest-account-session-ubuntu-1304/) on how to disable the guest account.

Comment: There's no indication that OP wants to disable the guest account

Answer (score -1):

After unsuccessfully trying other solutions, I tried examining my `~/.profile`. I could not find any error in it, so I deleted `~/.profile` and rebooted the system. It worked fine.

It is good to find errors and fix them in `~/.profile` but if you cannot, try deleting the file.

Comment: No need for that. You can overwrite it with the default fresh version in `/etc/skel`